# How to delete old image after updating in laravel?

Tags: laravel

name of controller is "EmployeeController", How i can delete old image after updating. Please help me.
This is my update function in controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $employee = Employee::find($id);

    $request->validate([
        'first_name' =>  'required',
        'last_name' =>  'required',
        'profile_image' =>  'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

    $profile_image = $request->file('profile_image');

    $new_name = rand() . '.' . $profile_image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $profile_image->move(public_path('profile_image'), $new_name);
    $employee->first_name = $request->first_name;
    $employee->last_name = $request->last_name;
    $employee->profile_image = $new_name;

    // $employee->delete('/profile_image/'.$employee->profile_image);

    if($request->hasFile('image')){
        //
    }

    $employee->save();

    return redirect('employees')->with('success', 'Data Added successfully.');
}
```

This is my Edit function in controller

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $employee = Employee::find($id);

    return view('employees.edit', compact('employee'));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
                $imagePath = public_path('employeeImg/'.$user->image);
                if(File::exists($imagePath)){
                    unlink($imagePath);
                }
               
            }
```

you can check if image exist then unlink from path and then save new

Answer (score 1):

First, you get the image url of the relevant id value from the database. You can then delete the relevant data using the Storage :: delete () function. See details here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#deleting-files

Answer (score 1):

First Thing You Should know how you are saving the images inside the database, get the path of them and use this simple delete.

Ex :

```
File::delete(public_path('storage/'.$user->image));
```

also u must check if the image column is not empty, if it is not empty it must delete it with the code above. else it'll just upload it without deleting anything.